# Books and references virtual microphone

Tags: signal-analysis

- What are some applications of virtual microphones (as in here http://sail.usc.edu/aigaion2/index.php/attachments/single/119.)?
- Are there good references (books or comprehensive tutorial papers) for this technology?

Comment: can you please describe exactly what you mean by **virtual**

Comment: The reference is a useful application of a 3D audio field sampling, which involves the 3D re-placement of resampling microphones in a 3D virtual audio field produced within a computer audio simulation rather than an actual physical enviroment, whose field of **applications** is expected to follow that of the **viewpoint cameras** of the computer graphics analog...

Comment: No I don't know such a book.